# Send multiple terminal commands with inputs, in one shell. On Mac

Tags: python, shell, terminal, subprocess, adb

I want access a device via adb shell commands. The device is connected via USB.
Manually I can access that via the terminal with the following commands in the sequence:

1. `cd /Users/xx/xx/`    # Change to path
2. `./adb shell`         # access the add shell
3. enter password        # the terminal expects a input of a password
4. run some more commands within the adb shell

What I have tried:

```
subprocess.run('cd /Users/michael/Documents/platform-tools/ ;./adb shell', shell=True)
```

it requires me to input the password, for that I wanted to use the input function:

```
subprocess.run('cd /Users/michael/Documents/platform-tools/ ;./adb shell', shell=True, input=*password*)
```

When I run that I get the error for the input variable: "**TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**".

For what I have understood, the 'commands' I send in step 3&4 are not real terminal commands, but inputs for the adb shell.

Can someone tell me, how I can solve that problem and automate this process in python?

Comment: Try putting `b` in front of the string that contains the password. Does this work?

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error asks for a bytes-like object, not a string.

To turn a string literal into a bytes-like object, append `b` before the string. Put `b` in front of the string that contains the password, something like `b"password"`.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem, what you only need to do is giving `inputs` the correct type of argument. For that just convert your string to bytes using for example `str.encode('UTF-8')` or you can use the `bytes()` method.

You can even just add a 'b' before your string like `b'password'`.

Here is a [tutorial](https://flexiple.com/python-string-to-bytes/).